# Prove that $\min_\limits{x\in\{-1,1\}^n} \lVert Ax\rVert_\infty≤ C\sqrt{n\log(n)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

I’m struggling a lot since few hours on this exercice and I really have no idea how to make the log appears.

The problem is the following:

Let $A$ be a matrix of size $n\times n$ whose entries $a_{ij}$ are such that $\left|a_{ij}\right|\leqslant1$.

Prove that there exists $C>0$ a constant that doesn’t depend on $n$ such that:

$\min_\limits{x\in\{-1;1\}^n}$  $\lVert Ax\rVert_{\infty}\leqslant C\sqrt{n\log(n)}$

I did a lot of exercises dealing with inequalities of matrix norm but I really have no idea for this one.

I learnt about Jensen inequality but it led me nowhere.

Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: What does “$d$” represent ?

Comment: I'm sorry it's n

Comment: Do you mean that $x$ is a vector whose components are all $-1$ and $1$ ? For example, $x=\big(\!-\!1;1;\ldots;-1\big)$.

Comment: Yep exactly, I understand it like you. It's written as I wrote it, in the exercice

Comment: If you want moderators not to close your question, you should read and do all what the following link says : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 8):

**Idea:** use the [probabilistic method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method).

Namely, come up with some distribution $D$ over $\{-1,1\}^n$ such that
$$
\Pr_{x\sim D}[\|Ax\|_\infty > C\sqrt{n\log n}]
 < 1$$
for some $C>0$. This implies there exists a realization $x^\ast$ for which the inequality  $\|Ax^\ast\|_\infty \leq  C\sqrt{n\log n}$ holds.

Moreover, to show that $
\Pr_{x\sim D}[\|Ax\|_\infty > C\sqrt{n\log n}]
 < 1$, by a union bound it is enough to show that $
\Pr_{x\sim D}[(Ax)_i  > C\sqrt{n\log n}]
 < \frac{1}{n}$ for every fixed choice $i$ of coordinate. *(Can you see why?)*

**More details:**  a natural candidate for $D$ is just the uniform distribution on $\{-1,1\}^n$, i.e., the coordinates of $x$ are i.i.d. Rademacher. Then, by a [Hoeffding bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality), for every fixed $1\leq i\leq n$ and every $t>0$,
$$
\mathbb{E}[(Ax)_i] = 0, \qquad \Pr[ |(Ax)_i| > t] \leq e^{-\frac{t^2}{2n}}
$$
and so, for any $t > \sqrt{2n\ln n}$, we get that, for any fixed $1\leq i\leq n$
$$
\Pr[ |(Ax)_i| > t] < \frac{1}{n}
$$
By a union bound over all $n$ coordinates, this gives
$$
\Pr[\|Ax\|_\infty > t] = \Pr[ \forall 1\leq i \leq n,\, |(Ax)_i| > t] < 1
$$
and you can conclude. *(For instance, $C=\sqrt{2.1}$ works.)*

Comment: Thanks for this great idea! I guess it can be even more simple. If P[(Ax)_i > t] < 1/n holds for every i from 1 to n, as ||Ax||_infinite = max for i in {1,...,n} of |(Ax)_i|. Then ||Ax||_infinite = |(Ax)_k| for k the the indice of the max. Hence as the statement holds for every i, it holds for k, so one has P[(Ax)_k > t] < 1/n ≤1.

Comment: @g0dLose You still have to take the union bound over all $i$, though, which is where you get the $\log n$ from, or, rather, why we set the probability to $1/n$ (the bound from Hoeffding holds for any fixed $i$, but you don't know which one corresponds to the maximum -- it's not a fixed $i$, that depends on the realization of $x$ itself. So you must get the guarantee for all $i$ to conclude)

Comment: I do agree, that one doesn't know which i is the maximum, however you know that the max is among one of those i. Hence, idk why one must take the union, instead of saying that "as it's true for all i, it will be true for the max that is one of those i".

Comment: I guess it's because as you said that "it's not a fixed i, that depends on the realization of x itself". I have to think about it again, I'm probably missing something.